# 1 wire to 2 wire bidirectional UART

Tags: uart, ttl, bidirectional, 1-wire

I'm working on diagnostics program for my old GM diesel, the old GM diagnostics uses a 1 wire bi directional serial protocol, 5v HIGH, 0v LOW, with the PCM data line being held high when idle, and the decoded data is in HEX format. I'm planning to use a level shifter (TXS0104ERGYR) to deal with the voltage difference from the ESP32 controller and vehicle PCM but my question is how to actually interface/wire the ESP TXd and RXd pins.

My concern is when the ESP is transmitting it will be transmitting to itself which could interfere with the readings, and the ALDL wire needs to be brought low before the ESP transmits. Is there a simpler way to do this in the software or would some kind or transistor circuit like what's pictured below be required?

OR Is my ADHD getting the better of me and I'm concerned about this for no reason, because my thinking leads me to believe the ESP and PCM wont be communicating at the same exact time. The ESP sends a request, the PCM listens to this request, the PCM responds with the requested data, and the ESP listens to the data sent. So I could just ignore the RXd pin while transmitting commands from ESP and only listen to it when the PCM is transmitting.

I appreciate any and all help, and I apologize if I may have already answered my own question, I don't have any electrical engineering friends so I only have myself and the internet to refer to and sometimes I drive myself crazy overthinking stupid simple problems, It just helps to get a second opinion sometimes.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any useful reference material I could look at with respect to the GM 1 wire bi directional serial protocol? I don't want to spend my time searching for it, if you already have a good source. I'd like to see both the electrical and behavioral spec, plus the protocol spec, if possible. I am starting from zero and there's no way I can offer thoughts without knowing more than zero and just guessing.

Comment: Your circuit has good chances, use 3.3 V as VCC and use a smaller pull up resistor at UART receive (<=3.3k). The Tx side is not perfect, the 3.3 V high of the ESP + 0.7V from transistor and resistor will clamp ALSL to 4V, but this should be read as high. If you don't want to receive your own transmissions make PD5 high during that.

Comment: jonk, Here is a good reference of the ALDL protocol, but unfortunately there isn't much useful info on the hardware side other than the 2nd page tagged here and the circuit I posted originally.  ALDL Protocol= https://pcmhacking.net/forums/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=219  Hardware= https://www.techedge.com.au/vehicle/aldl8192/8192hw.htm

Comment: Jonk here is another good writeup, its also where I found the schematic I posted above https://lukeskaff.com/projects/car/gm-obd-i-obd1-aldl-microcontroller-lcd-interface-scan-tool/

Answer (score 2):

Sneaky use of the upwards-pointing-arrow of the top PNP.  Efficiently drawn, but requires visualizing Vcc simultaneously going both downwards and upwards.  As Dave Jones would say, "trap for young players!"

The PD5 pin output, low, means "allow receive PD0" and high means "receive PD0 always high."  Unless there's some specific reason to use this enable feature, I'd say just tie that collector to ground (permanently "allow receive".) This will let the software receive all transmits, which can be used to verify that the TX happened properly.  (Could potentially spot a collision this way, when the TX doesn't match the same RX.)

Admission: I know nothing of "ALDL" so am just offering what insight I can since nobody else has chimed in.  The circuit looks purpose-built for "ALDL" though so I'd recommend it be followed.  Simply because it looks like the ECU is expecting to be interfaced this way. ESP pins to open-collector (half of this schematic) could work, but this schematic's impedances are already set, and it includes a nice activity indicator, so why not just follow it. (It's less of a gamble than rolling-your-own.) If using 3.3V instead of 5V logic, will likely want to use a smaller pull-up resistor for UART RX.  Some experimentation will be needed.

The next question is, are you prepared to "talk" *GM Diagnostics* language to it?  All digital data is 0's and 1's, low and high, and can be represented in hex.  That's only half the battle though - then you need to know what data to send, and even how long to wait between bits/bytes/frames/whatever.  And for the returned data (if any), how is it encoded/decoded?  Sometimes this is "standard" and trivial (such as 9600 baud, N-8-1 RS232 raw), but it can quickly get complicated (think Profibus 12Mbaud 7-E-1 RS485, encoded packet results, expected master TX packets within a certain timeframe, etc.)

If you have a library for this, then great, that might handle 90% of it.  Expect to still do some tweaking though as something this esoteric is likely to include "surprises."

If no library, then the road forward might get a *little bumpy* at best.  You'd probably want to use a logic analyzer to figure out what TX/RX is happening with a regular device connected, and emulate that with yours.

Comment: I cant take credit for the posted circuit, its from a college project I found online here https://lukeskaff.com/projects/car/gm-obd-i-obd1-aldl-microcontroller-lcd-interface-scan-tool/ Its different in what hes trying to accomplish but the means are the same either way. I'm not worried about decoding as Ive found a definition list for the specific PCM Im working on. I really appreciate your reply, you've confirmed my initial thoughts and listening to what the ESP transmits to confirm proper transmission is a great idea!

Comment: Also according to the lukeskaff project, the ALDL is standard uart with 8 data bits, 1 stop, and no parity @8192  baud. I've included a link to where I got the PCM definition for anyone reading this in the future, Im using the A225 one. http://www.gearhead-efi.com/Fuel-Injection/showthread.php?661-16183977-PCM-Information-EC-Turbo-Diesel